# How can I export a dataframe to csv line by line?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe and three columns, title, head and text, when I export to csv title and head are on the same line but since the text column has text it occupies several lines, how can I make each row of the dataframe to be in one line?

```
    Title       headline                                           Text

1   Agriculture http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agriculture #REDIRECT   [[Agriculture in ancient Greece]] 
                                                                    {{...
2   fragments   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Habitat_fragmentation   {{Infobox Historic 
                                                                    building\r\n|image=The Abbe...
```

The output is

```
Agriculture,http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agriculture #REDIRECT,[[Agriculture in ancient Greece]] 
                                                                    {{...
fragments,http://dbpedia.org/resource/Habitat_fragmentation,{{Infobox Historic 
                                                                    building\r\n|image=The Abbe...
```

But output should be:

```
Agriculture,http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agriculture #REDIRECT,[[Agriculture in ancient Greece]]{{...
fragments,http://dbpedia.org/resource/Habitat_fragmentation,{{Infobox Historic building\r\n|image=The Abbe...
```

Comment: If `df.to_csv` is adding line breaks in to your text (because you do have line breaks in your text), you need to remove the line breaks from the dataframe

Comment: make sure word wrap is off in your text editor, in case you already have the output you want :)